# rmagick resize image keeping proportions

Tags: rmagick

I want to resize images with different sizes with rmagick using only the width. I need to keep the proportions in example 640px width. The point is, if image is bigger than 640px, it should be made smaller to 640px. However, if the image is smaller than 640 it should not scale to 640, it should do nothing.

I thought this was the purpose of change_geometry, but somehow is not working for me. This is my example, but it´s always scaling all images to 640px.

```
photo = Magick::Image.read(name).first        
photoMedium = photo.change_geometry!("640") { |cols, rows, img|
   img.resize!(cols, rows)
} 
# ... write photoMedium
```

**UPDATE:**

Well, I thought that was the purpose of change_geometry. Anyway, I guess you can always check the columns and if it´s bigger than 640 the resize, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [resize_to_fit](https://rmagick.github.io/image3.html#resize_to_fit) method.

Comment: resize_to_fit always scale to the width. In case the original image is smaller it will scale it to the size. This is not depicted requirement.